# how to modify specific nested object in array in a document with mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have a document with needed _id field. i need to modify one of the elements in dialogs array,

```
{
  _id: "ZiKtWniMnXHjMz8jD", 
  profile: {
    dialogs: 
      [
        {
          messages: [],
          name: "Bill",
          partnerId: "T3HYQeA8b9GwQ2bAE",
        },
        {
          messages: [],
          name: "Bob,
          "partnerId: "Tw26fWCzqjLsdoSim"
        },
        {
          messages: [],
          name: "Barbara",
          partnerId: "dkuBFgHdox7pGnu68"
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

how to push anything into messages array of an object which name field is equal to "Bob"?

Comment: Are trying to run it the console or as a single statement in a program? as a fall back this can be done as Java-script statement in the console

Comment: thank  you guys! i have seen that question which you marked as duplicate and that  helped me a lot. everything works now! may the force be with you!